# Right Click Context Menu in IE - Add new items

Tags: internet-explorer, registry, contextmenu

Adding items to the registry item

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\ I can successfully create new options in the Internet Explorer right click menu.

Trouble is, I only want to show the item if the user right clicks on a link.

In other words it would appear at the same time as the option "Open in new window"

I imagine it's the setting of the "Contexts" value... anyone know what the value should be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values are as below...

Default 0x1, 
Images 0x2, 
Controls 0x4,
Tables 0x8, 
Text selection 0x10, 
Anchor 0x20

You can see them on the following link from msdn...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753589(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I've read that, but it doesn't answer my question. Using the above link, what should I user for hyperlink?

Comment: It's Anchor as in 0x20 for a hyperlink (<a></a>/link/anchor tag)